# How can I repair this damaged air compressor?

Tags: repair, compressor

I have an 8 Gal CH air compressor (HM700099AV). Purchased about 3 years ago. Used for a few months, then stored behind other items in a shed and never drained until a year later. At that same time, the bottom twist valve (underneath the tank in the center - it's an upright tank) broke off at the stem. I used another smaller tank since then but want to try and fix the 8 Gal tank now. Air leaks out the hole in the bottom of the tank now where a broken valve was.

The bottom twist valve broke off and I think a thin rod about 12-15" long came out. I don't recall as it was a couple years ago and I had 5 kids running around that day. I put the tank aside again, but am taking a shot at it today.
 It was about $160 new and worked great when it was cared for properly.

If a rod did come out, what parts do I need to fix it?
Is it possible that this not worth it to repair?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the rod might have been, the inside of an air tank is pretty simple.

Replacement drain valves are available in a variety of configurations, and generally they thread into a nut welded into the tank. It's then just a matter of finding an appropriate replacement valve (relatively easy) and removing the old one (probably much harder).

[image: replacement valve]

To help get the frozen valve out, you could (should) try penetrating oil to free what are almost certainly frozen threads, but you may need to step up to using a torch to apply heat to help break the part loose.

Comment: I agree with heat but use caution as the tank is a pressure vessel getting it two hot can fatigue the metal.